# C - function that creates linked list only returns first node

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have found other questions that were similar but not quite exactly the same, if I'm mistaken please leave a link :)

I've been trying to implement a shell with C and while parsing with pipes in mind I thought about using a linked list of   `char** args` .

My parsing function has issues returning the entire list. I use a tmp node to keep moving while creating new nodes, but when I want to return the original head, it's next is NULL, I thought the pointer tmp to my head was supposed to be just a pointer and that changes have to be made on my head.

Here is simplified code with only the issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
} node ;
node* foo()
{
    node* head=malloc(sizeof(node));
    node* tmp=head;
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        tmp=tmp->next;
        tmp=malloc(sizeof(node));
        tmp->data=i;
    }
    return head;
}
int main()
{
    node* list=foo();
    while(list)
    {
        printf("this is your %d\n",list->data);
        list=list->next;
    }
}
```

if you could just point me in the right direction or tell me what I'm getting wrong that'll be great.

Comment: First time you come here: `tmp = tmp->next`, `tmp->next` has never been initialized.

Comment: I malloc'd it afterwards with the `tmp=malloc(sizeof(node))`

Comment: That's the problem. You malloced it _afterwards_. You probably have a serious misconception about how programming works.

Comment: And `tmp=tmp->next; tmp=malloc(sizeof(node));`doesn't make sense, its just like writing `a = 5; a = 10`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `malloc` tmp->next before assigning it to tmp, like this:

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    tmp->next = malloc(sizeof(node));
    tmp=tmp->next;
    tmp->data=i;
    tmp->next = NULL;
}
```

This outputs:

```
this is your 0
this is your 0
this is your 1
this is your 2
this is your 3
this is your 4
```

Comment: ...and `tmp->next= 0;` as `malloc` does not initialize the memory(hence you wouldn't know where the list ends).

Comment: so I need to set tmp->next as NULL everytime ?

Comment: Although a bit better than the original program, this is still wrong.

Comment: Reda, you are currently allocating a list of length 5 so you know the length. I assume that is for testing, so in "real life" you add a node, do something, append a node, etc. Any process that walks the list will want to know ehere the end is, and that is where `next` is zero. So you set `next` to zero at the point where you are done. Whether that is "every time" or at some point is logic I leave to you.

Comment: I edited my answer to add the initialization of `next` as @PaulOgilvie mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

```
node* head=malloc(sizeof(node));
node* tmp=head;
int i=0;
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    tmp=tmp->next;
    tmp=malloc(sizeof(node));
    tmp->data=i;
}
return head;
```

Here you have created head and gave space, but you have never initialized it and returning it before you initialized it

Answer (score 1):

The function does not make sense because the data member next of each allocated node is not initialized. It is the variable `tmp` that is being changed in the loop.

The function can look the following way

```
node* foo()
{
    const int N = 5;
    node *head = NULL;

    node **current = &head;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        *current = malloc(sizeof( node ) );

        if ( *current )
        {
            ( *current )->data = i;
            ( *current )->next = NULL;
            current = &( *current )->next;
        }
    }

    return head;
}
```

Instead of using the magic number `5` it is better to specify how many nodes should be created in the list and the initial value as function parameters.

For example

```
node* foo( size_t n, int init_value )
{
    node *head = NULL;

    node **current = &head;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        *current = malloc(sizeof( node ) );

        if ( *current )
        {
            ( *current )->data = init_value++;
            ( *current )->next = NULL;
            current = &( *current )->next;
        }
    }

    return head;
}
```

Take into account that in main the pointer list is overwritten in the loop. So you will not be able to access the list one more because the address of the head node will be lost. Use an intermediate variable. For example

```
int main( void )
{
    node *list = foo();
    for ( node *current = list; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        printf("this is your %d\n", current->data);
    }
}
```

And according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Comment: I see absolutely no need for your double indirection. Just malloc head and then tmp=head and later return head will work fine.

Comment: yes, In my actual program I do that, I just simplified to emphasize on the problem, instead of posting my whole code :P

Comment: @PaulOgilvie The function can be implemented in different ways. It does not mean that if there exists another way to implement the function then the current way is incorrect.:)

Comment: Sorry, Vlad, I agree with that; however, for the current uder, already struggling, you make things too complex with your double indirection. KISS is prefered.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie You are mistaken. It is my implementation that is simple and does not have partial cases. Moreover it can be made more general without any changes in the logic as I showed in the second function implementation. The less the qualification of a programmer the more partial cases his code contains. And on the other hand the higher the qualification of a programmer the more generic code he writes.